# Rails ActionView::MissingTemplate with Devise in API mode (format: json)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, devise

I'm getting an error from Devise when I set a request to, for example, `/api/v1/users/#{user.id}.json`

```
Missing template api/v1/devise/registrations/edit, devise/registrations/edit, devise/edit, application/edit with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}
```

but my app is running in API mode and I want that return a **json user object**

Devise controller parent class is:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.parent_controller = 'Api::V1::StoreController'
end
```

StoreController:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class StoreController < ApplicationController
    end
  end
end
```

And ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
end
```

How can I do that with Devise? In all other controllers (non Devise) it works good, return always a json object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in order to specified the default format of your route

```rb
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v1
    devise_for :users
  end
end
```

I guess you created the proper json response under the routes, for example in **/api/v1/users/sign_in** there is a controller with a json response.

The other thing I can see is what are you trying to do has nothing to do with devise, with the route **/api/v1/users/:id** you have to have a controller like this:

```
  class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :show

    def show
      render json: current_user, status: :ok
    end
  end
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it works but I would like to do that with default Devise controller not with custom controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a proper solution as well, not successful yet. However, I found a workaround in [this topic](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23923#issuecomment-189728223) by rendering as below

```
render plain: your_json_object.to_json, content_type: 'application/json'
```

and it works with default devise controllers as well.